# Ceeb code for college

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have started filling the graduate application form. When I tried to fill the academic details, I'm required to enter Ceeb code, but I searched on my transcript, and Internet, and I didn't get the code. Without the code, I couldn't save the details.

I sent mail to the department but I didn't get any reply, perhaps due to the vacation.

EDIT: I am from Bangladesh. How can I get that code?

Comment: What are you asking here?  Right now, you have simply stated a situation, but no question.

Comment: https://sat.collegeboard.org/register/sat-code-search

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that your question has been stemmed from the raised ambiguity about the CEEB code and its utilization:

You should provide the CEEB code of the university, at which have you passed your undergraduate studies. They are supposed to send some document (e.g. official transcripts) to the target university, as a part of your application.

You could find some more details about CEEB codes from [here](https://embarksupport.zendesk.com/entries/31074-What-is-a-CEEB-code-How-do-I-use-the-school-code-search-) and [here](http://blog.prepscholar.com/what-are-ceeb-codes-your-questions-answered)...

Best

Comment: I am from Bangladesh. How can I get that code?

Comment: You need to ask about it from your undergraduate university, and then report it as a part of your application...